# Проблема создания кастомного видеоплеера на kivy/kivymd

Tags: python, python-3.x, видео, kivy, kivymd

Пытаюсь написать кастомный видеоплеер на kivymd и kivy,
столкнулся с несколькими проблемами:

1. непонятно как выводить время воспроизведения видео(например: 01:32/3:10)
2. не получается изменять время видео при помощи `MDSlider`.

Пожалуйста, как можно реализовать решение двух этих проблем. Всем заранее спасибо! :)

Ниже привожу пример kv файла кастомного видеоплеера:

```
<CustomPlayer@MDBoxLayout>
    vid: "videos/video.mp4"
    pre: "images/preview.jpg"
    orientation: "vertical"

    Video:
        id: vid
        source: root.vid
        preview: root.pre

    MDBoxLayout:
        adaptive_height: True

        MDIconButton:
            id: stop
            icon: "stop-circle-outline"

        MDIconButton:
            id: pl_pa
            icon: "play-circle-outline"
            on_press: app.pause_play(root)

        MDIconButton:
            id: volume
            icon: "volume-high"

        MDSlider:
            id: slider
            value: root.ids.vid.position
            max: root.ids.vid.duration

            #Здесь безуспешно пытаюсь изменить время воспроизведения видео

            on_touch_move: root.ids.vid.seek(percent=self.value)

        MDLabel
            adaptive_width: True
            id: lbl
```